# Can you execute a task repeatedly in Java?

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks

Is it possible to repeatedly execute a task each day, each minute, each second, each year? I want it to run like a daemon.

I need a scheduled task to search the database continuously; if it finds a certain value then it should execute a further task.

Comment: What do you mean by `each day each minute each second each year` ? You want to run a task, once a year ?

Comment: No each and everytime as i said like a daemon

Comment: In order to do tasks based on time you would want to use threads. Check out this link in order to learn more about them: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/threads.html

Comment: Hmm so the program is going to be running all the time? Might want to look into <a href="http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#Timer(boolean)"> Java Timer </a>

Comment: @AzharAlam Why not use an actual daemon thread? What do you mean by specifically by "like a daemon"?

Comment: Consider using database triggers instead of polling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to ask whether it is possible to repeatedly

You can use a loop, or  a ScheduleExecutorService, or a Timer, or Quartz.

> each day each minute each second each year

So once a second.

> I want it to run like a daemon.

I would just make it a daemon thread then. No need to make it "like" a daemon.

> if it find the correct value then it should do the remaining task.

Simple enough.

Read the data, check the value and if its what you want do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a look at the [java.util.Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) or [Quartz Scheduler](http://quartz-scheduler.org/) would be helpful.

A [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html) might also be helpful. Look into their example code and you should be able to do it.