# Repeated execution of a java file

Tags: java

I have a java file which i want to execute repeatedly on a machine. The file should be executed automatically as soon as the previous instance of the file execution is over. How to achieve this?

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: This may help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11912659/executing-a-task-repeatedly-in-java

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html

Comment: how do you going to execute java file? Is that a class with some methods? Is there `public static void main()` method defined?

Answer (score 2):

Use bash script in a loop call your executable

```
for i in 1 2 3 4 5 .. N
do
    java executable
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Java provides an environment in which a program will function as you (or someone else) have written it.

The operating system specifics will determine how that program is started.  If you want the program to launch each time the previous copy has finished, you need to wrap the launching of the java program with a loop in the scripting language supported by that operating system, or convert the program to be a system service / daemon.

Other techniques exist, but they actually don't launch the second program *after* the first completes.  They either:

1. Launch a second copy of the program immediately (unless already found).  The program is written to do nothing while it can detect it's "launcher" is running.  Upon loss of one process, the second becomes responsible for the processing (and the launching of it's standby failover).
2. Capture shut down / crash events and launch a copy of the program when quitting, which actually has two programs running at the same time, but for a short duration.  This is commonly done; but is technically unsound as there are many ways a program might crash before being able to launch a new process.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a simple perl or python script that would work on both windows and linux.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$N = 100;
for($i = 0; $i < $N; $i++){
    system('/full/path/to/java -cp full_class_path my.class.Name');
}
```

You can call this script in a java file or execute it on command line.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("perl script.pl")
```